# Insider threat and Office 365 - STIGs or similar results?

Tags: security, microsoft-office-365

Office 365 is a convenient way to keep work in-synch between multiple computers and smart phones.  However, for cases where one is contractually obligated to safe guard and protect a client data and documents, the insider threat issue is a very real concern (for example, HIPAA Compliance for Health related data, Intellectual Property concerns or sensitive materials).

Could anyone direct me to a recent (within the last year) white paper or results of a test of Office 365 against formal STIGs or similar security testing conducted in the presence of a third party or government witness?

Comment: I believe this question is both off topic for serverfault and disallowed wrt asking for white papers.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft posts a number of audits it has passed and a summary of results in the Trust Center.
https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-trust-center-welcome

MS is only protecting and compliant up to where the service is enabled.  Once you turn it on you are responsible for any further requirements in securing the service. While they will issue say a HIPAA BAA, this would just be something you reference and you would have trust/inherit the security controls.

Things like HITECH and ISO27001 can be applied to a cloud service - but if you need things like FISMA or other Government controls you will not be looking at a public cloud but the Government (Government agencies only) specific or private hosting that Microsoft provides.